# foreach для экземпляров класса

Tags: c#, foreach

Как организовать foreach для экземпляров класса FileInfo? Пытался сделать вот так:

```
FileInfo[] fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles(); //создаём массив из fileInfo всех файлов
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileInfos[number].FullName); //экземпляр fileInfos, 
                                                  //над которым будут проводиться действия
foreach (FileInfo file in fileInfos) //для каждого файла из тех, что в директории
{
   StreamReader //читаем файл
   if (...) //условие к содержимому файла
   doSomething //если условие выполняется, делаем что-нибудь
}
```

Но, очевидно не выходит, поскольку, фактически, внутри foreach я снова объявляю уже существующую переменную `file`, что делает невозможным её использование дальше. Перелопатил уже несколько тредов с похожими вопросами, но там, в основном, используют `foreach` с массивами или коллекциями, созданными вручную, и никаких проблем не встречается. Постарался, насколько умею, закомментировать этот набросок кода, чтобы было понятнее, чего я пытаюсь сделать. Не могу понять, как это реализовать, если вообще можно.

Comment: вот эту строчку уберите `FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileInfos[number].FullName); //экземпляр fileInfos, 
                                                  //над которым будут проводиться действия`

Comment: Точно! Получается, что внутри foreach конструируются экземпляры с заданным именем, и над ними уже делаются действия. Спасибо :)

Comment: FileInfo file <- На кажой итерации цикла в эту переменную закладывается объект возвращаемый fileInfos.GetEnumerator().Current

Comment: У меня было подозрение на это, когда писал код, ещё думалось: "А зачем же внутри foreach ещё раз объявлять переменную, я же уже написал конструктор выше?". Но мозг сказал, что не может быть так просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у каждого файла в 'c:\temp' надо обработать строки:

```
foreach(var file in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\temp")) {
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(file);
    // ...
}
```

EnumerateFiles и ReadLines возвращают IEnumerable (т.е. целиком данные не загружаются в память), и поэтому в `c:\temp` может быть любое количество файлов, а сами файлы могут содержать миллионы строк -- OutOfMemoryException не возникнет.

Comment: У меня почему-то ругается на метод EnumerateFiles. Говорит, System.IO.Directory не содержит определения для него. Пробовал и полную ссылку на метод записывать, как у вас, и неявно определять - не хочет распознавать.

Comment: @bravo4827 какая версия Visual Studio и .NET? метод добавили в .NET 4 - см. [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx), а реализация на C# - [тут](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,a9450441125c1b2e)

Comment: .NET 4 стоит. Скорее всего, лучше 4.5 поставить, да? Работаю под MVS12

Comment: Извиняюсь уже за оффтоп, но странно... Установщик дотнет считает, что версия 4.5 уже установлена, а в реестре её нет 0_о

Comment: чем новее - тем лучше. можно поставить Visual Studio 2015 Community - бесплатная. ее установка включает .NET 4.6.1

Comment: Понял, где была проблема: в целевой версии проекта стояло .NET 3.5, поэтому использовалась сборка библиотеки из этой версии. Но за совет спасибо, не знал, что майки сделали MVS бесплатной :)